# Win API wrong textbox output

Tags: winapi, type-conversion

I've been tying to build a simple Win Api program (using CodeBlocks) and ran into a weird problem.

```
case WM_COMMAND:{
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == Calculate) {
            int A=0, ArrayReset = 0;
            char textread[256];
            SendMessage((HWND)Box1,(UINT) EM_GETLINE, (WPARAM)1, (LPARAM)&textread);
            A = atoi(textread);
            itoa(ArrayReset, textread, 10);

            itoa(A, textread, 10);
            SendMessage((HWND)Box1,(UINT) WM_SETTEXT, (WPARAM)1,(LPARAM)&textread);
```

(My program is a bit more complicated, but this is just to show the problematic point)
Now, what I expect the code to do is to read the value in Box1, convert it into integer, convert it back to char array, and print this array back on the same Box1. Basically, some converting with no difference in the end result. 
However, there is this strange problem. The code works with single digit numbers just fine, but if I enter a number with more digits, like 12 or 356, I get 1200 and 3560 respectively. If the input number is bigger than a thousand, it works fine again.
Is this a problem because of my method of resetting array's value back to 0, or does it have to do something with the conversion processes?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have several problems there.

First, you didn't show us what `Parse1` is. Beware that you must set the size of the buffer in the first word of the buffer. Also, why do you pass 1 as the `WPARAM`? This is the zero-based index of the line to retrieve from a multiline edit control, but is ignored if the edit is single line.

Also, what is with the first `itoa` call?

Here is an example that works:

```
TCHAR textread[256] = {0};
*(reinterpret_cast<WORD*>(&textread)) = 256;
::SendMessage(hwnd, EM_GETLINE, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&textread));

auto n = _ttoi(textread);

_itot_s(n, textread, 256, 10);

::SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETTEXT, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&textread));
```

Comment: Parse1 should actually be textread. I was copying part of my code and changing variables to make them more understandable. Guess I overlooked one.
I wasn't sure what WARAM does, kinda new at this
The first itoa call was to delete all the previous data in the array.
Thank you for the example, but it doesn't seem to work for me. 
Got errors telling me that "ISO C++ forbids declaration of `n' with no type"
and
"_itot_s' undeclared (first use this function)"

Comment: `auto` is new in C++11, so you must be using an older compiler.

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in this code.

For starters, `(LPARAM)&textread` should be either `(LPARAM)textread` or `(LPARAM)&textread[0]`.

But more importantly, you are not preparing the [`EM_GETLINE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761584.aspx) message correctly:

> lParam
>   A pointer to the buffer that receives a copy of the line. **Before sending the message, set the first word of this buffer to the size, in TCHARs, of the buffer.** For ANSI text, this is the number of bytes; for Unicode text, this is the number of characters. **The size in the first word is overwritten by the copied line.**

Try this instead:

```
case WM_COMMAND:{
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == Calculate) {
        int A = 0;
        TCHAR textread[256];

        *((LPWORD)&textread) = 256; // <-- add this
        SendMessage(Box1, EM_GETLINE, 0, (LPARAM)textread);

        _stscanf(textread, _T("%d"), &A);
        _stprintf(textread, _T("%d"), A);

        SendMessage(Box1, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)textread);
    }
    break;
```

Comment: Or just use `GetDlgItemInt`.